# Hand written DFT vs MATLAB FFT has flipped conjugates?

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, dft

I had to compute the DFT of a signal with 5 points with a hand-written method and using MATLAB's FFT just to see if they are equal. Taking the absolute value of both gives the same spectrum, however the conjugates are in a different order for both. Why is this?

values using handwritten DFT, negative conjugates first

[image: values using handwritten DFT, negative conjugates first]

values using MATLAB FFT, positive conjugates first

[image: values using MATLAB FFT, positive conjugates first]

The code I used is shown below

```
Now we compute the DFT of the finite sequence to show that DFT is 
actually a sampled version of the DTFT.  


N=5;
W=exp(-1i*2*pi/N); %the complex term W_N defined in lecture 2;
DFTmatrix = W.^((0:N-1)'*(0:N-1)); %the DFT matrix of size N
%Multiply the DFT matrix with the time-domain samples to get DFT
DFTofTruncatedSampledSignal = DFTmatrix*sampledsignal.';

Task 5:
FFTSpectrum =fft(sampledsignal,N)'; %MATLAB fft function to compute DFT
```

Comment: The matrix multiplication in MATLAB is a complex conjugate multiplication.

Comment: @Dan: No, it is not.

Comment: Ah my mistake- it is the transpose that’s is the complex conjugate. Thanks @CrisLuengo

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem might be in this line:

```
FFTSpectrum = fft(sampledsignal,N)';
```

Note that in MATLAB, `'` is the complex conjugate transpose. Use `.'` to transpose a matrix without applying the complex conjugation.